# how to install cronie that requires dailyjobs

Tags: linux, cron, centos6

I'm installing HDP 2.6 on centos 6(no internet access on that machine) and its required redhat-lsb-core->crontabs->cronie->dailyjobs.
I googled for dailyjobs (cronie-anacron), but yum localinstall says:

needs cronie = 1.4.4-16.el6_8.2.

This is vicious circle.
Please help me find out how to localinstall cronie

Answer (score 1):

Install cronie and cronie-anacron at same time. They have dependencies crossed.

`rpm -i cronie-xxxx.rpm cronie-anacron-xxxx.rpm`

Comment: This is something no one mentions. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

solved this only mounted repo dvd iso centos. dunno why this rpm not installed without it